# Elastic Search Multiple Fields

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Tire to index and search a database of cars:

```
create :mappings => {
    :cars => {
        :properties => {
            :id => {:type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => true},
            :user_id => {:type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed'},
            :name => {:type => 'string', :analyzer => 'snowball' },
            :time => {:type => 'long', :index => 'not_analyzed'},
            :origin_country => {:type => 'string', :analyzer => 'keyword', :include_in_all => false},
            :origin_state => {:type => 'string', :analyzer => 'keyword', :include_in_all => false},
            :origin_city => {:type => 'string', :analyzer => 'keyword', :include_in_all => false},
            :dealer_name => {:type => 'string', :analyzer => 'snowball', :boost => 1.5, :include_in_all => false}
        }
    }
}
```

And queries look like:

```
   s = Tire.search Search.index_name do

      query do |query|
        query.text :_all, downcased_query, :type => :phrase
      end

    end
```

Right now if you search for "New York Joe Dealer" it will match if there is a dealer_name is "Joe Dealer" or if the origin_state is "New York" but not both. Is there a way to match origin_state is "New York" and "dealer_name" is "Joe Dealer" (or either)? The idea is I want a user to enter in a fre-form query string and be able to find the best matches possible and to a user they would expect to enter New York Joe Dealer and find all cars sold at Joe Dealer in New York (or all cars in New York or at Joe Dealer ranked lower).

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution would be to use the [`multi_match`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/) query to perform the same query against multiple fields. It's supported in Tire, see https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/match_query_test.rb.

```
Tire.search Search.index_name do
  query do |query|
    query.match :dealer_name, downcased_query
    query.match :origin_state, downcased_query
  end
end
```

You can even use the `phrase` type if the query would contain both the dealer and state info in correct order, such as "New York Joe Dealer".

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move to a "match" type filter, and diable :type => :phrase, so:

```
query do |query|
    query.match :_all, downcased_query
end
```

There are still some issues with sorting so that time is still a big input, but this resolves many of the issues.